# re.findall(str(list[0]) is searching for the first character in the list item, not the full string

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a program to find all of the IPv4 addresses in a log file and display how many times these addresses occur. I am using Python's re library. It works great until I try and iterate through the list of addresses to count how many times they occur. When I call an item from the list and convert it to a string, re.findall() will only search for the first character in that string, not the string itself.

When I pass in a full string, it works perfectly fine, and when I print the item from the list as a string, it also shows the full address. I've also tried using the str() method at different places in the code, this does not seem to fix the issue. Also the re.findall() method requires a string.

The string that was created looks like this: 
[['111.222.333.124'], ['111.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.124'], ['111.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.124'], ['111.222.333.125'], ['111.222.333.125'], ['11.222.333.123'], ['111.222.333.126']]

```
def findDuplicates(list):
    string_list = str(list)
    target = list[0]
    x = len(re.findall(str(target) , string_list))
    print(target, " occurs ", x, "times!")
```

['111.222.333.124']  occurs  217 times!

This address occurs 3 times in the log file. and the number 1 occurs 217 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok quick question: if you're looking for items in a list wherein the items are identical to the object you're looking for, why not compare the whole item?  In general, re is reserved for when you're trying to find partial matches, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing here.  Something like:

```
counter = 0
for i in list:
    if i == target:
        counter+=1
print(counter)
```

I would wager a guess that what happens to you is when you str(list) you are getting '111.222.333.124' and then when you do `list[0]` you are getting `1`, so then `1` is getting fed into `re.findall` for the matches.  I would check that.

Comment: Yup that works! Had no idea for loops could work with arrays like that in Python. Thanks!